# How to get the name of a console in Windows?

Tags: windows, console

Is possible to get the name of a console in Windows? Just like is done by the C function *ttyname* in Unix systems

Comment: This probably won't be terribly useful to you, since they'll all be called "Command Prompt".

Comment: @Mark, not necessarily. You can change the title of the command window when you open it. (Create a shortcut to a command prompt window, view the properties, and change the 'General' tab's description from `Command Prompt` to `Mark's Command Prompt`, for instance. Now start the command prompt from that shortcut and read the title.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WinAPI [`GetConsoleTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to retrieve it.

You might find [links to all of the console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) useful.

You didn't specify a language, so [here's the one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in C++ from MSDN

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main( void )
{
   TCHAR szOldTitle[MAX_PATH];
   TCHAR szNewTitle[MAX_PATH];

   // Save current console title.

   if( GetConsoleTitle(szOldTitle, MAX_PATH) )
   {
      // Build new console title string.

      StringCchPrintf(szNewTitle, MAX_PATH, TEXT("TEST: %s"), szOldTitle);

      // Set console title to new title
      if( !SetConsoleTitle(szNewTitle) )
      {
         _tprintf(TEXT("SetConsoleTitle failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         _tprintf(TEXT("SetConsoleTitle succeeded.\n"));
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```